# Alternate for template engines in express

Tags: express

I dove into express.j and encountered pug (template engine).Now, i don't like the idea of writing code that works very similar to HMTL+ some identation.I'd rather stick with normal HTML.I want to discard view engines altogether . Is there another way to hook these html,css and javascript files instead of pug.I read Angular is utilized. Could someone elaborately with a form examlple,styled with css and how to integrate Angular with express.js . Perhaps any tutorial available online...

P.S. Please refrain from using too much technical terminology..I'm a noob. Simple english is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest to keep your front end part separate(angular) and bakcend(node REST api).

Comment: If you're trying to insert data into an HTML template, then you will seriously benefit from using some sort of template engine.  There are dozens of choices so you can find the one that has a format you like or dislike the least, but none will be pure HTML because they need additional syntax to let you direct how things should be modified with live data.  Angular also uses modifications to the HTML syntax and then inserts data client-side rather than server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '[handlebarsjs](https://handlebarsjs.com)'.

That is a great tutorial to get start.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1srD3Mdvf50

Good luck.